# Server returning HTTP 404 error on HTTPS connection. 200 on HTTP connection

Tags: ssl, windows

I have a client app talking to a secure server implementing IPP (internet printing protocol), using WinHttp library.

```
HINTERNET m_hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(m_hConnect, L"POST",L"/ipp",
                                L"HTTP/1.1", WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
                                WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
                                m_secure); //WINHTTP_SECURE
 if (!m_hRequest){
    printf("WinHttpOpenRequest: Error %d has occurred.",GetLastError());
    return 0;
}
```

// No client certificate is presented as the server does not need one.

```
bResults = WinHttpSetOption( m_hRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, WINHTTP_NO_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, 0); 
 if (!bResults){
    printf("WinHttpSetOption: Error %d has occurred.",GetLastError());
    return 0;
}
```

// Ignore security errors like unknown CA and CN not matching URL

```
DWORD secIgnore = SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID | SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA | SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID | SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_WRONG_USAGE;
    bResults = WinHttpSetOption(m_hRequest,WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS,&secIgnore,sizeof(DWORD));
     if (!bResults){
        printf("WinHttpSetOption: Error %d has occurred.",GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }               
bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(m_hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 0, 0);
 if (!bResults){
    printf("WinHttpSendRequest: Error %d has occurred.",GetLastError());
    return 0;
}               

bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(m_hRequest, NULL);
```

Now I am supposed to get a 200 OK and IPP response in the content.
What I get instead is 404 resource not found.

Other observations:
. The same piece of code works going to port 631 (default)
. OpenSSL to issue the same POST command. It gets the proper response
. A similar software implemented using raw sockets and Windows SChannel seems to work fine
. SSL handshake seems to be fine ending with encrypted application data flowing both ways (verified in Wireshark)

I am puzzled as to why it is failing.

Is it a problem in WinHttp?
 Is the server SSL version not correct?
 I still strongly suspect something going wrong in the SSL layer

Could someone please help. I can provide Wireshark logs if needed.

Thanks,
Shyam.

Comment: If it would be at the SSL layer you would not be able to get a 404 back. Check again that the request you are doing with openssl is exactly the same as you are doing with your program and that you are using the same IP:port as target.

Answer (score 2):

This seems more a problem with the sever configuration. A example: if you use a apache 2 server you can configure the location of the content in de default-site and default-ssl-site different. When this is done you would have a other location where the Webserver search for content and returns 404 because it is not there